# Is it possible to say that "numbers fluctuate quite a lot" in the English language?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is it possible to say that "numbers fluctuate quite a lot" in the English language, meaning that they are extremely different? Or it sounds a little bit weird for natives? I want to say that there are a lot of sources providing some kind of statistical information and the numbers or figures "fluctuate quite a lot" from source to source. Would be a pleasure to hear your thoughts.

Comment: The fragment you have given is wrong, as the number 7 (for example) doesn't fluctuate at all. It might be better to talk about the *data* being different between different sources. Also, do you mean that different sources provide different data items, or that the values of the data items are different. If it is the latter you may be able to quantify the variability.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that I provided not the best example to explain my idea. Here is the sentence for you to have a better image: The media double-crossed us with exoplanets and various sources name different numbers of our potential future houses. The numbers fluctuate quite a lot. 24 thousand, 4 thousand or even 300 million. So is it possible to say "fluctuate quite a lot" in this context or there is a better idiomatic expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *fluctuate* means, roughly, to *change between values*, so it doesn't really sound right to say that the numbers *fluctuate* between sources.  (The root of the word *fluctuate* actually comes from the same place as *flow* - something that moves.)  From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fluctuate):

> 1 : to shift back and forth uncertainly 
> 2 : to rise and fall in or as if in waves

We might say that the numbers fluctuate *from year to year*, because the numbers are changing over time.  For example,

> [Numbers fluctuate widely year to year...](https://books.google.com/books?id=7wfDJR58_r8C&pg=PA201&dq=%22numbers%20fluctuate%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiK_qu-9ff1AhWDjYkEHZtXDusQ6AF6BAgDEAI)

If we were talking about different sources, it would be more natural to say that the numbers *differ* or *vary* a lot, because they are different from each other.  For example,

> [Predator numbers varied significantly in relation to sampling position and station...](https://books.google.com/books?id=T1HTWszYCKMC&pg=PA19&dq=%22numbers%20varied%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjlj5mE9vf1AhV1jYkEHT2FAfwQ6AF6BAgCEAI)

> [Estimates of population numbers differed from the measured population...](https://books.google.com/books?id=oPUgAAAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA303&dq=%22numbers%20differed%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiLmsjC9vf1AhWLkokEHeAyCF0Q6AF6BAgEEAI)